# Aligning views in opposite directions in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have run into an issue where I need to align 2 views on opposite ends of a container. E.g. leading and trailing alignment in `HStack` and top and bottom in `ZStack`. I've tried everything and it just does not work. Also can't find anything similar on the web. Here is the simplest example

```
struct AlignTest: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: Alignment.top) {
        Color.white
        Color.red.opacity(0.5).frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        Color.blue.opacity(0.5).frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .bottom)
    }
  }
}
```

Which produces the result on the image below. It aligns both boxes at the top but I want them to be aligned at the top and the bottom. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is:

```
ZStack(alignment: Alignment.top) {
    Color.white
    VStack {
       Color.red.opacity(0.5).frame(width: 50, height: 50)
       Spacer()
       Color.blue.opacity(0.5).frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .bottom)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's easy until you want it to use more precise positioning. :)